# Hide group rows of dc.dataTable

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I am using the JavaScript library [dc.js](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) to dynamically generate a table of records using the `dc.dataTable()`. The data is rather simple, so I actually want to show it as a plain list of rows without any grouping.

However, `dc.dataTable()` requires a `.group()` attribute. Each such group is then shown with an extra row in the resulting table before its data rows.

```
var datatable = dc.dataTable("#category-table");
    datatable
        .dimension(categoryDim)
        .group(function(d) {return "Categories";}) //just 1 static group, so it's only 1 unnecessary group label row at least
        .columns([
          function(d) { return d.category_name; },
          function(d) { return d.views;},
        ]);
```

If I skip the `.group()` part, I get

> Mandatory attribute chart.group is missing on chart

Is there any way to hide these group label rows or skip the grouping altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding the table group rows is possible using css. These added rows have the css class `dc-table-group` and can therefore be hidden using some custom css:

```
.dc-table-group {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Nice. There is also a PR for this, but this is simpler. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/863

Answer (score 0):

Update 2019:

As of version 3.0.12 you can hide the group (or section) header with 
`.showGroups(false)`.

Docs:
https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html#showGroups__anchor